# How do I use matplotlib.ConciseDateConverter with a Seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

> EDIT for clarity: I would like to avoid casting the datetime to string using strftime. I would like the axis to intelligently scale as with ConcisedDateConverter, and I would like to retain the years to differentiate the dates below as shown in the example. e.g. I might have 5 years worth of data, with repeating dates, but only need to show the year on Jan 1st of every year so as to not clutter the axis.

I am attempting to format my seaborn heatmap dates axis using the matplolib `ConciseDateFormatter()`, however it does not appear to work. Following the guide in [the matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html) I have tried both adding it to the registry:

```
converter = mdates.ConciseDateConverter()
munits.registry[np.datetime64] = converter
munits.registry[datetime.date] = converter
munits.registry[datetime.datetime] = converter
```

and in the code itself as:

```
    locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=7)
    formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

however, when I run the heatmap function, the plot x-axis labels seem unchanged. My code is below:

```
d1 = datetime.date(day=10, month= 5, year = 2020)
d2 = datetime.date(day=15, month= 6, year = 2020)
d3 = datetime.date(day=20, month= 7, year = 2020)
d4 = datetime.date(day=10, month= 5, year = 2021)
d5 = datetime.date(day=15, month= 6, year = 2021)
d6 = datetime.date(day=20, month= 7, year = 2022)
dates = [d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6]

s1 = 100
s2 = 150
s3 = 200

strikes = [s1,s2,s3]

chain = []
for d in dates:
  for s in strikes:
    val = random.randint(-100,100)
    o = [d,s,val]
    chain.append(o)

df = pd.DataFrame(chain, columns = ['Date','Strike','Value'])
df1 = df.pivot("Strike", "Date", "Value")

pal = sb.diverging_palette(0, 500, sep=1, n=5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))

# locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
# formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

sb.heatmap(df1, annot=True, fmt="d", center=0,cmap=pal, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

The output is as follows:

[Output Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYs4B.png)

I would like an output as follows with the month and date below each column and the year as needed to clarify:

[Desired Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ckN.png)

Is there any way to get the seaborn x-axis formatted as desired (or similar). I would like to avoid making a separate x-axis list and then running `date.strftime` and hard coding the strings. It would be nice to have the date semi-intelligently scale as with the example in the documentation above.

An interesting point to note is that if I put the

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

lines after the heatmap function, the process fails with a value error claiming not all the x values are datetimes. I have tried the obvious solution of converting the `datetime.date` objects to `datetime.datetime` but still the same error.

`ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. It would really help if you more concisely explain your issue. Here as far as I can tell, what you're trying to do is remove the years from your dates. I suggest using strtime https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, however I explicitly stated I would like to avoid casting the datetime to string using strftime. I would like the axis to intelligently scale as with ConcisedDateConverter, and I would like to retain the years to differentiate the dates below as shown in the example. e.g. I might have 5 years worth of data, with repeating dates, but only need to show the year on Jan 1st of every year so as to not clutter the axis.

Comment: In that case, you might want to use something like matplotlib setticklabels https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_ticklabels.html or perhaps for more complicated operations something like set_major_formatter https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.set_major_formatter.html

Comment: I am using set_major_formatter (as shown in my code), but that is not seeming to be passed to the seaborn heatmap

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the Seaborn heatmap function plots vs an integer in a range corresponding to the total number of x values, so it does not retain the datetime information. Thus it is impossible to use set_major_formatter with a seaborn histogram. I am going to try and do the same using `imshow`